# jQuery change event with variable assigned to function is not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a function that is working well in all browsers, but not in IE11.  It does a call  to a variable-assigned function:

```
var getStuff = function() {
        alert('getting stuff'); 
        ...
}
```

And here is the call that doesn't appear to work in IE.

```
$('form input[name!="stuff"]').change(getStuff);
```

What gives? I've tried alternatives such as using .on("change"...) but haven't been successful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code, as provided (hence with provisos) works fine in IE11, just tested it; but can't provide a fiddle/pen as IE11 is too antiquated.  So:  do you have any console errors?  Are you running your js before or after the HTML exists?  Are you adding HTML dynamically?  Is this the *only* code on the page or is something else breaking before it gets to your code?  Does it work in any other browser (with/without other code) *edit* you say it does, but what about with just that code.  There's a lot of things that don't work in ye olde IE11, but none of them are in your question.

Comment: Here's the entire .html page tested in IE11: https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IUYEB  - copy that, save as a new .html on your server and open in IE11 - does it work?

Comment: Great questions!  I found that it is due to another line in that function (designated by the ellipses). Thanks for your input. I'd rather not use IE11.  It is antiquated.  However, some users still use it and so I have to get things to run on it.  Something within the function fails in IE11 but works elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an inclusive form of your selector `$('form input[name!="stuff"]')` OR put in a not or a `.filter()` form of the not

```
$('form').find('input')
    .not('[name="stuff"]')
    .on("change", getStuff );`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your input.  After looking further into it, it is due the way an object is created and the jQuery change does in fact work in IE11.

Comment: From your last comment and from this answer, it looks like you had found the cause of the issue and possible solution for it. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.